# Phantomjs amir20 unable to use sessions in both onResourceReceived and onResourceRequested

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Hi I'm using Amir's phantomjs: https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node

and I'm trying to use sessions for each visited page. The thing is it looks like I need to put a true param value for the onSourceRequested:

```js
currentPage.on('onResourceRequested', true, onResourceRequested);
```

```js
function onResourceRequested(requestData, networkRequest) {
networkRequest.setHeader
//here I can create the session using the same IP
```

but this disables my other function onResourceReceived which is not executed.

```js
currentPage.on('onResourceReceived', onResourceReceived);

function onResourceReceived(responseData, networkRequest) {
//I can't enter here
}
```

Is there a work around? Can I pass another parameter or something so I can get my responseData from onResourceReceived function?